# Trying to open a new FXML file dynamically from Controller class in JavaFX gives error

Tags: java, javafx

**MY SOLUTION**

In the end the problem relied on the fact that I instantiated in the initialization method an ImageView that only existed on *principal.fxml*, and so, whenever I started a new scene, the controller looked for that ImageView, thus giving a NullPointerException.
I just removed that initialization for the image and added it through the fxml. I don't know if this is the best way to do it, but it worked well for me.

---

I have a JavaFX application that has the following classes and FXML files:

- Main.java that extends Application and has the start method
- Controller.java that controls all my FXML files, and from where I want to open dynamically the scenes
- principal.fxml
- test.fxml
- final.fxml

My application starts with **principal.fxml**. I want to open my **test.fxml** scene after the user clicks on a button on the principal scene, after getting an XML file for later processing.
And finally, in the test scene, again when the user clicks on a button, I want to open the **final.fxml** scene.

My project structure is the following:

```
├── res
│   ├── css
│   │   └── estils.css
│   ├── imatges
│   │   └── logoFinal.png
│   ├── view
│   │   ├── final.fxml
│   │   ├── principal.fxml
│   │   └── test.fxml
│   └── xml
│       └── testAngles.xml
├── SERRANO_PEJO_M03UF5.iml
└── src
    └── jtest
        ├── Controlador.java
        └── Main.java
```

My **Main.java** code is the following:

```
package jtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/view/principal.fxml"));
        Parent root = loader.load();
        /*Controlador controlador = (Controlador)loader.getController();
        controlador.setStageAnd*/

        primaryStage.setTitle("jTest");

        Scene escena = new Scene(root, 640, 400);
        escena.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/css/estils.css").toExternalForm());

        primaryStage.setScene(escena);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

And my **Action method (in Controller.java)** to open the new scene is the following:

```
@FXML
    public void carregaTestAction (ActionEvent event) {
        // Mostra un diàleg amb la selecció de l'arxiu
        FileChooser seleccioArxiu = new FileChooser();
        seleccioArxiu.setTitle("Selecciona l'arxiu de test");
        arxiuTest = seleccioArxiu.showOpenDialog(btCarrega.getScene().getWindow());

        // Carrega el nou stage, TEST
        stage = (Stage) btCarrega.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/test.fxml"));
            Scene sceneTest = new Scene(root, 640, 400);
            stage.setScene(sceneTest);
            stage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

And this is my error stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace: 
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/biel/Documents/M03UF5/SERRANO_PEJO_M03UF5/out/production/SERRANO_PEJO_M03UF5/view/test.fxml

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2603)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3237)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3194)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3163)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3136)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3113)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3106)
    at jtest.Controlador.carregaTestAction(Controlador.java:148)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1782)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1670)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8879)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:200)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:206)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1200(Scene.java:3579)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1849)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2588)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:397)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:434)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:390)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:433)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at jtest.Controlador.initialize(Controlador.java:95)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
    ... 66 more
```

I also tried only with this code (which gave us our teacher), but it gave me an error too:

```
@FXML
    public void carregaTestAction (ActionEvent event) {
        // Mostra un diàleg amb la selecció de l'arxiu
        FileChooser seleccioArxiu = new FileChooser();
        seleccioArxiu.setTitle("Selecciona l'arxiu de test");
        arxiuTest = seleccioArxiu.showOpenDialog(btCarrega.getScene().getWindow());

        // Carrega el nou stage, TEST
        stage = (Stage) btCarrega.getScene().getWindow();
        Parent root;
        try {
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/view/test.fxml"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

I searched and found [Javafx: Open a new FXML from another Java Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706973/javafx-open-a-new-fxml-from-another-java-class), ["FXMLLoader.constructLoadException" when trying to run java fx application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31135192/fxmlloader-constructloadexception-when-trying-to-run-java-fx-application) and [JavaFX open a new scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29080759/javafx-open-a-new-scene), but I still can't understand how this should work and why is it giving me this error.

**EDIT:** I know what a NullPointerException is, but I don't understand how, even with the code I have, I can't open a new scene. I thought it might be because it didn't get my *test.fxml* file the right way, but it IS getting my *principal.fxml* file without any issues in my main class, and an image file in my Controller class.

**EDIT 2 (2019-03-22 00:31):** I revised my Stacktrace and now I understand why you addressed me to the NullPointer question.
In my initialize method in my Controller class, I get an image, only for my **principal.fxml** scene:

```
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        // PRINCIPAL.FXML

        // Insereix la imatge del logo
        Image imatgeLogo = new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/imatges/logoFinal.png"));
        ivLogo.setImage(imatgeLogo);
    }
```

What I understand from this exception is that when I try to initialize the other stages, the controller doesn't find an ImageView to get? If this is it, how can I make the controller get the image ONLY when it is starting my **principal.fxml** scene? Thank you and sorry for any inconvenience and misunderstanding.

Comment: I still don't think this should be marked as a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it, since I do know what a NullPointerException is, and in that question there is really no answer to mine. I suspect my current problem is in my initialization method on my controller, because I try to set an image only on my principal scene, but I still don't know how to make it so it charges the image ONLY in my principal scene.

Comment: I just tried commenting the part of code where I add my image and, indeed, it opened my other scene. So the problem is in fact on the imageview. I guess the best way to add that Image is through my fxml file?